# is there a way to make my code work in a descending way?

Tags: python-3.x

```
height = float(input("enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))

bmi = round(weight / height ** 2)
if bmi < 35:
 print(f'Your BMI is {bmi}, you are obese.')
elif bmi < 30:
 print(f'Your BMI is {bmi}, you are slightly overweight')
elif bmi < 25:
 print(f'Your BMI is {bmi}, you have a normal weight')
elif bmi < 18.5:
 print(f'Your BMI is {bmi}, you are underweight ')
else:
 print(f'your bmi is {bmi}, you are clinically obese')
```

why wont it work if i start by 35 then going down
and it only work if i start from 18.5 going up

Comment: Any BMI which is under 35 will match first `if`, and that's it...

Comment: Can you name a number that is at least 35 but less than 30?

Comment: 35 is greater than all the numbers you have listed, 18.5 is less than 25 so it will satisfy that condition.

Answer (score -2):

I will suggest you start the code with the highest range and using >= for the conditions; the code will check the conditions in descending order.

Example

```
height = float(input("enter your height in m: "))
weight = float(input("enter your weight in kg: "))

bmi = round(weight / height ** 2)
if bmi >= 35:
 print('Your BMI is {bmi}, you are obese.')
elif bmi >= 30:
 print('Your BMI is {bmi}, you are slightly overweight')
elif bmi >= 25:
 print('Your BMI is {bmi}, you have a normal weight')
elif bmi >= 18.5:
 print('Your BMI is {bmi}, you are underweight ')
else:
 print('your bmi is {bmi}, you are clinically obese')
```

And I noticed you have

```
print(f'Your BMI is {bmi}, you are obese.')
```

instead of

```
print('Your BMI is {bmi}, you are obese.')
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is "why"?

Comment: Also, OP is using f-strings correctly